# Test templates and variables used in Tornadoweb

Tags: python, unit-testing, tornado

I'm testing the MainHandler using the code below.

```
import tornado.httpserver 
import tornado.httpclient 
import tornado.ioloop 
import tornado.web 
import unittest 

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler): 
    def get(self): 
        kwargs = {'name' : 'world'}
        self.render('template.html', **kwargs)

class TestTornadoWeb(unittest.TestCase): 
    http_server = None        response = None 

    def setUp(self): 
        application = tornado.web.Application([ 
                (r'/', MainHandler), 
                ])   
        self.http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application) 
        self.http_server.listen(8888) 

    def tearDown(self): 
        self.http_server.stop() 

    def handle_request(self, response): 
        self.response = response 
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop() 

    def testHelloWorldHandler(self): 
        http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient() 
        http_client.fetch('http://localhost:8888/', self.handle_request) 
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start() 
        self.failIf(self.response.error) 
        self.assertEqual(self.response.body, 'Hello, world') 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    unittest.main()
```

The template.html:

```
Hello, {{name}}
```

I wanna test the template and its variables.
How I can test if name was received correctly?

There's some attribute that I can use to do the asserts or this should be done another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's essentially what you're already doing in your assertion. Since the client instance is pulling the rendered template, you can't match the template variable. By using your kwargs in the template, it's rendering those kwargs into the template - where {{name}} is 'world' (the expected output), your template variable has been received and rendered.

If you need to test specific output, a fairly inelegant solution could be to assign each variable a meaningless `<div>` tag (i.e., `<div name="name">{{name}}</div>`) and then use the `assertIn` method (i.e., `self.assertIn(self.response.body, '<div name="name">world</div>')`) to test for the correct output.